# Mapping scancodes to keycodes

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The Archwiki article [Map scancodes to keycodes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) states

> Mapping scancodes to keycodes is universal and not specific to Linux console or Xorg [...]

while the Archwiki article [Extra keyboard keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys) (which the former article suggests to read) states

> Note that the keycodes are different for Linux console and Xorg.

Which of the two is true? Or am I getting something wrong and it is no contradiction at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keycodes are *numerically* different: The X keycode value is derived by adding 8 (the value of `MIN_KEYCODE`) to the Linux input layer keycode, as you can see in the source of [evdev.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-evdev/tree/src/evdev.c#n280), line 280. Apart from this, they are identical (same order, same meaning).

Mapping scancodes to keycodes is actually done *per input device*, so it's not "universal" in this sense: you can connect two USB keyboards to the computer and give each keyboard its own mapping; funnily, there doesn't seem to be standard utility program to do this. However, the resulting keycodes will be the same for the Linux console and X (ignoring the numerical difference).

Comment: Thanks. Searched a lot of internet saying all kinds of things before finding this.  Very valuable and underrated answer.